# Able to use App Registration without client secret

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, owin, azure-app-registration

I've been working through transitioning an old webforms app to use Azure AD authentication, everything is working fine however I noticed that although I added a client secret to the app registration, my web app is able to authenticate without passing the client secret.

Is this normal behavior? I'm probably missing something simple here but I was under the impression that creating a client secret means that auth requests to this app reg must include the client secret otherwise Azure AD would assume the request has come from an unauthorized app.

In my StartupAuth I'm simply just ommitting the client secret (deliberately for testing purposes)

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions() With {
        .ClientId = clientId,
        .Authority = authority,
        .RedirectUri = redirectUri,
        .PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
        .Notifications = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications() With {
            .AuthenticationFailed = Function(context) System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0),
            .SecurityTokenValidated = Function(context)
                                          Return OnSecurityTokenValidated(context)
                                      End Function
        }}
    )
```

I'm able to get an ID token without providing the client secret but I was expecting it to reject the request.

Comment: From what I understand, to just authenticate a user may not require a client secret, and would rely on the "Redirect URIs" to ensure the token is sent to the correct location after the user is authenticated. However, if you were to try to do something on behalf of that user (i.e. call a downstream Web API on behalf of that user) then it would require a client secret. The `scopes` during the auth request would control what a token would have access to.  I have not had a chance to actually test this end to end though without using a client secret.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't seen that mentioned anywhere. Maybe my understanding of the purpose of client secrets/certificates is totally off, I thought they were a mechanism for the application itself to identify itself to AAD, so that if the tenant/client Ids were exposed somehow and a malicious user created an app to use that app reg, it would fail because of the missing certificate/secret. I also tested adding a certificate instead of secret and it also works fine without providing the certificate at all.

Comment: The "Redirect URIs" which are setup under the Authentication section in the AAD app registration would also keep a malicious user from creating another app that used that app reg, because they would never be able to get the auth token because the auth server would send it back to the "Redirect URI" which you control.  They wouldn't be able to intercept, because they wouldn't be able to use a "Redirect URI" which wasn't setup in the AAD app or they would get an auth error.

Comment: This makes sense, strange in all the samples and tutorials it's never mentioned that a secret/certificate isn't required if you're strictly only doing AD auth and nothing further, I thought I would add more security by using a certificate then went nuts trying to figure out why it made no difference and I could still authenticate without it

Comment: After reading more, it sounds like it could be related to hybrid auth flow, which is enabled by checking the "ID token" checkbox under "Authentication/Implicit grant and hybrid flows" in the AAD app registration. I agree it is difficult to find explicit docs, but makes sense since you wouldn't be able to do anything on behalf of the user bc to get an access token would require client/app auth w secret/cert + the user auth. The closest I've found to docs for this is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-id-token-as-well-or-hybrid-flow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the authorization code flow, starts with requesting an `authorization code` for a user. This process authenticates the user and let's you know the user is who they say they are, and is where they would authorize any access requested by your app (if it contains permissions for reading their user profile for example). This is the section circled in green in the image below. **This step does not appear to require any client secret** since it doesn't actually give your app client access to resources on that user's behalf unless you also have the app client secret/cert to use for the `access token` later.

After authentication, if you want to do anything as that user (call a Web API as that user for example), then you need an `access token` and that is where you have to use the `authorization code` from the first step plus your app client secret/cert to get the `access token`. This is the section circled in red below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#protocol-details

[image]

If you are just authenticating the client and never actually need to access resources on behalf of that user, then you would not need to use your AAD app client secret. I wasn't able to find any official Microsoft documentation that explicitly states this, and the closest I found was: https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/hybrid-flow which states:

> If your application only needs to use Hybrid Flow for sign-on, you
> will not need a Refresh Token or an Access Token, only an ID Token
> with claims.

This is also implied in the docs here, where the client secret/cert isn't mentioned until the access token section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#redeem-a-code-for-an-access-token Also note that certificate credentials are preferred over client secrets.

> **Redeem a code for an access token** All confidential clients have a
> choice of using client secrets or certificate credentials. Symmetric
> shared secrets are generated by the Microsoft identity platform.
> For best security, we recommend using certificate credentials. Public
> clients, which include native applications and single page apps, must
> not use secrets or certificates when redeeming an authorization code.
> Always ensure that your redirect URIs include the type of application
> and are unique.

Comment: I think this is the accurate answer for my particilar situation, since our App reg isn't doing anything other than authenticating a user it's possible the client secret/certificate is never required in that flow. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> **Note** that: Client secret is required for confidential web applications. If your application is configured as public client, then there is no need of passing client secret.

If the **`Allow public client flows`** is enabled as **yes** then the application is public client, and you will be able to use App Registration without client secret.

[image]

For **sample**, I generated access token without passing client secret:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/token

client_id : xxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
grant_type : password
scope : https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read
username : user@********.onmicrosoft.com
password : ******
```

[image]

If you want to use client secret, then set the **`Allow public client flows`** is enabled to NO.

**Reference:**

[Delegated access token without client secret - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1085114/delegated-access-token-without-client-secret) CarlZhao-MSFT

Comment: Thanks Imran, the Allow public client flows was already set to No